Need help understanding negative largest Lyapynov exponent in system featuring continuous symmetries
I am currently playing around with calculating Lyapunov spectra for different systems and for one particular system I am struggling to interpret the obtained spectrum.
The system in question features pattern forming behavior (stripes, squares, hexagons, spots, etc) and under certain circumstances these patterns can start moving translationally .
Now my understanding is that systems featuring continuous symmetries will have a largest Lyapunov exponent of 0. This is indeed what I obtain when the patterns are static. However once they start moving the largest exponent becomes negative in this case and I have no idea why.
Of course this could be due to numerical errors, but my algorithm seems to work fine for systems with well known spectra (Lorenz, Kuramoto–Sivashinsky equation etc).
Is there any reasonable explanation for this or should I simply examine my code further?

For ODEs at least one Lyapunov exponent — corresponding to the direction of the flow for a typical trajectory — should be zero. For non-chaotic, dissipative systems all other exponents are negative.
But what are the phase space variables of this system? Choosing convenient coordinates always helps (random reference). Could it be that, for instance, stationary patterns appear in the system's phase space as indifferent equilibria while moving patterns as attracting cycles?

Thank you for the reference. I will look into it. The system I am talking about is a PDE of some 2D scalar field, or set of coupled PDEs, up to fourth order in space.  So If I understood  this correctly I should have some zero exponents no? I do not see why the discussion in the reference would not hold in the case of patterns exhibiting purely drifting/translational motion.
